# Exchange: Receive admin mails without mailbox license

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I'm managing a very small (only 2 active accounts) Exchange environment on Microsoft 365 for a friend.

I have an account coder14@friendscompany.com which I can use to login and configure everything.
However, that account has no license linked to it.

Of course, I want to receive administration mails (like for example requesting mail flow from the past). But I can't find a way to set a forward an that mail address (I want to forward the mails to my personal gmail).

Is there any way to do this, or is there no other option than to ask my friend to buy another license, just for this?

Online I've found tutorials explaining to create a mail user. However, when trying to create a mail user on the address coder14@friendscompany.be I get the error this address is already in use.
Mailing to coder14@friendscompany.be returns an error saying this mailbox does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge and test, an active user which has not been assigned license doesn't have the mail feature and basic features(e.g. Outlook, Word, OneDrive e.g.), the following snapshots display the differences between active user without license and one with license(In other words, the account without license isn't really a mailbox):

**Mail**:

[image]
[image]

**Outlook, Word, OneDrive, etc.**:

[image]

[image]

To forward(Add a **To/CC/BCC** recipient) emails which are sent from administration to your personal email address, I think you could create a **transport rule** which is like the following snapshot:

[image]

Comment: This worked: creating a mail contact with coder14@friendscompany.be as external mail address. Then create a mail rule to forward all mails sent to that contact, to my personal mail address. Thanks!